# css - Select every element depending on the parity of amount of parents ( CSS or Less but no JS )

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, less

[ I know I probably didn't explain the problem in the title well enough. ]

So, I'm working on a style-sheet where there are two custom elements ( `<grid>` and `<box>`) that are flexboxes, and alternate in `flex-direction`, so like:

```html
<box>             <!-- flex-direction: column -->
  <grid>           <!-- flex-direction: row -->
    <box></box>     <!-- flex-direction: column -->
    <box></box>     <!-- flex-direction: column -->
  </grid>
  <box>            <!-- flex-direction: row -->
    <grid></grid>   <!-- flex-direction: column -->
  </box>
</box>
```

In less, my best solution was:

```
grid, box { display: flex }
body {
 > grid, > box {
   flex-direction: column;
 > grid, > box {
   flex-direction: row;
 > grid, > box {
   flex-direction: column;
   // Etc...
 }}}
}
```

And this is pretty bad, is there something like the code below in css?

```
grid, box { display: flex }
body > grid:parents(even), body > box:parents(even) { flex-direction: column }
body > grid:parents( odd), body > box:parents( odd) { flex-direction: row }
```

EDIT: body > nth-child() doesn't work.

Code:

```css
body > grid:nth-child(even),
body > box:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: column;
}

body > grid:nth-child(odd),
body > box:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-direction: row;
```

1. `body > element:nth-child(odd)` only selects the first immediate child of body, it should be `body element:nth-child(odd)`.
2. My HTML example at the start of the question looks like this using the code above when modified to fix problem number 1.

```html
<box>             <!-- flex-direction: column -->
  <grid>           <!-- flex-direction: row -->
    <box></box>     <!-- flex-direction: column -->
    <box></box>     <!-- flex-direction: row -->
  </grid>
  <box>            <!-- flex-direction: column -->
    <grid></grid>   <!-- flex-direction: row -->
  </box>
</box>
```

Which isn't the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed something obvious, something simple like this should achieve the same:

```
grid,
box {
  display: flex
}

body > grid:nth-child(even),
body > box:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: column;
}

body > grid:nth-child(odd),
body > box:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-direction: row;
```

}

You can use `nth-child` to determine the `even`-ness or `odd`-ness of the parent element and derive the rules from there.

Comment: 10/10, I can also use less to shrink that with: `body{>box,>grid{&:nth-child(odd){/* odd code */}&:nth-child(even){/* even code */}}}`

Comment: I just found 2 problems, 1. `body /* whatever */` and not `body > /* whatever */` 2. The children of an element alternate flex direction themselves. I will explain this a little more in the question.